# devtools::check permission denied in Build panel

Tags: rstudio, devtools

Running `devtools::check` in the Console works but doing it through the Build panel fails with: `cannot create file '/mnt/my_package.tar.gz', reason 'Permission denied'`

What can I do to change the folder where the check is done from? I've tried with `--output=/mnt/code/tmo --path=/mnt/code/tmo` in Build options without luck.

I am using R Studio Server 1.4.1106

Answer (score 0):

I this there is something wrong with the permissions in your system. Open **RStudio** after right-clicking on the icon, choose **Run as Administrator** and this should solve the permission problem. The reason for this is that some permission only belongs to the administrator. Good Luck.

Comment: thanks, this is RStudio server and you are right, the folder does not have the right permissions but I can't change them unfortunately. I was hoping I could change the folder where `check` creates any temporal files tho'

Comment: @Julio I suggest changing your working directory using `setwd('The path to a new folder')`. Just consider using slash (`/`) instead of backslash (\\) when defining the new directory through the path.